# PHP preg_match is not recognizing properly?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a **preg_match** statement like so:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-z\.\_\-]$/", $_POST['username'])
```

But it always equates to false.

```
"aaa" - false
"#$&Y#" - false
"   a#*$7"- false
```

WHY

Comment: Is your input actually as such -- ie, surrounded with double quotes? If yes, no wonder it fails

Comment: Also, no need to escape the dot, underscore or dash (since you are putting it at the end) here: `[0-9a-zA-Z._-]`

Comment: @fge Not true. Look at Rich Adams' answer. It works.

Comment: if you talk about `._-`, true -- try it and see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only matching one character, you need a `+` so that it matches one or more.

```
preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-z\.\_\-]+$/", $_POST['username'])
```

Comment: Also note `A-z` -- and that `.`, `_` and `-` need not be escaped